# Работа с текстовыми форматами epub, fb2 в php

Tags: php, fb2, epub

Возник такой вопрос: можно ли создать и/или открыть файлы формата epub/fb2 в php?
Если это возможно, опишите где можно либо прочитать об этом, либо подскажите специальные библиотеки.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Спецификация fb2](http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/index.html.en)

Ничего сложного там нет. Но если лень реализовывать, то на гитхабе есть готовые классы. [Например вот.](https://github.com/ThisNameWasFree/rude/blob/master/src/fb2.php)

[Спецификации на eput](http://idpf.org/epub/31)

Готовых решений тоже много. Гугл в помощь. [Например вот.](https://github.com/splitbrain/php-epub-meta)